# Have xcode 7 - need 6.4 with command line tools

Tags: ios, xcode

I have OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 with xcode 7 installed.

Now I have two development tools breaking after I installed xcode 7.

I need to revert back to 6.4 **with** command line tools?

Right now I am contemplating:

- Move xcode7 to a separate folder for future usage/safekeep
- Download xcode 6.4 and move it into /Applications/
- Download xcode 6.4 command line tools (can I still use terminal for this? 
  **Are command line tools still available for 6.4?**)
- Need the ios 8.4 SDK (and download it from where?)

Will this work? Is there a better way where I can switch between xcode versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple copies of `Xcode.app` installed in `/Applications`, you just need to rename them.

So I would recommend renaming them to `Xcode6.app` and `Xcode7.app` and then using `xcode-select`, or the Xcode Preferences, to decide which version of the Command Line tools to use.

You are probably better off downloading them from the [Apple Developer Download site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), and break your dependence on the Mac App Store installed version, otherwise it might keep hassling you with updates etc.